# Spring AOP - interceptor only executes first layer

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

example:

```
@Component
public class ExecutionClass extends ExtensionClass{
    public void doSomething(@MyAnnotation String hello){
        doSuperTask(hello);
    }
}

public class ExtensionClass{
    public void doSuperTask(@AnotherAnnotation String hello){
        doAnotherTask(hello);
    }

    public void doAnotherTask(@YetAnotherAnnotation String hello){
        //do some stuff
    }
}


@Override
@Around("execution(public * com.test..*(..))")
public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    //invoke whatever around method
}
```

However, this results in only `ExecutionClass#doSomething` AOP to be in effect, while the rest are ignored. How to fix and make the interceptor intercept every public method?

All have the package of `com.test.**`

Comment: Spring uses proxies, if you do method calls inside the proxy those won't be interested. A drawback of proxy based AOP.

Comment: any way to workaround this and make it trigger? other than autowiring a new class and putting the logic in that new class.

Comment: @theAnonymous self reference is a way to do this. Within `ExecutionClass` one can autowire a self reference like `@Autowired ExecutionClass self`. Now a call from `doSomething()` like `self.doSuperTask(hello);` will go through the proxy and gets intercepted

Comment: Either self invocation or by using full blown AspectJ with either load or compile time weaving.